# Make a p-type multicol span to full width

Tags: multicol, tabu

I'm using `longtabu` in my resume to display the content in 3 rows. In the first row of type `l` is the date, the second row contains the description (graduation, team member, ...) and is of the type `X` (which I redefined to type `L` to be left aligned) and the last row is of the type `r` and contains the place (society, university, ...).

In the second row, there should be a `multicol` spreading across the `L` and the `r` column. Here I want to print the graduation paper title or what exactly I've done as an employee. As I need the ability to put in a `\newline` in here, I need the `p` type for the `multicol`, but unfortunately this goes ahead with putting in a width for the `p{}`. I don't know that width as it depends on the content of the previous line so I want to do it automatically.

How can I achieve this result? Having a `multicol` spreading across the two columns as with the `l` type, but also allowing the use of `\newline`?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages and
% Package options
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{geometry, tabu, longtable, xparse, parskip}
\geometry{%
    verbose,%
    a4paper,%
    tmargin=25mm,%
    bmargin=25mm,%
    lmargin=25mm,%
    rmargin=20mm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    nohead,%
}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% New environment
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{entrylist}{m}%
{%
    {\LARGE\bfseries #1}
    \par%
    \addvspace{.5em}%
    \longtabu{@{} l L r @{}}%
}%
{%

    \endlongtabu
    \par\addvspace{2em}
}


% %%%%%%%%%%%
% New Command
% %%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\entryitem}[4]{
    #1
    &
    {\bfseries #2}
    &
    {\small\color{light-gray}{#3}}\\
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{p{6cm}}{\itshape #4}\\[.5\baselineskip]
}



% %%%%%%%%
% Document
% %%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{entrylist}{Test}
        \entryitem
            {2014 \textendash\ 2018}
            {Member of the foo research team}
            {Foo society}
            {Working on a new foo}

        \entryitem
            {2014}
            {Graduation to master of bar}
            {Bar school}
            {The juxtaposition of foo and bar}
    \end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76192/134144

Comment: I copied the exact code and I'm getting the following error: `Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 78.`. Could you please provide an MWE showing how this should be incorporated to my existing code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure, if I have adapted the code correctly, but the following example seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages and
% Package options
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{geometry, tabu, longtable, xparse, parskip}
\geometry{%
    verbose,%
    a4paper,%
    tmargin=25mm,%
    bmargin=25mm,%
    lmargin=25mm,%
    rmargin=20mm,%
    nomarginpar,%
    nohead,%
}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% New environment
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{entrylist}{m}%
{%
    {\LARGE\bfseries #1}
    \par%
    \addvspace{.5em}%
    \longtabu{@{} l L r @{}}%
}%
{%

    \endlongtabu
    \par\addvspace{2em}
}


% %%%%%%%%%%%
% New Command
% %%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\entryitem}[4]{
    #1
    &
    {\bfseries #2}
    &
    {\small\color{light-gray}{#3}}\\
    &
    \multicolumn{2}{p{6cm}}{\itshape #4}\\[.5\baselineskip]
}



% %%%%%%%%
% Document
% %%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\zzz
\ifx\LT@i\@undefined
\zzz=8cm
\else
\global\zzz\z@
\begingroup
\@tempcnta\z@
\def\LT@entry#1#2{%
\advance\@tempcnta\@ne
\ifnum\@tempcnta=1 \global\advance\zzz#2\relax\fi
\ifnum\@tempcnta=2 \global\advance\zzz#2\relax\fi
}
\LT@i
\endgroup
\advance\zzz-2\tabcolsep
\advance\zzz-\arrayrulewidth

    \begin{entrylist}{Test}
        \entryitem
            {2014 \textendash\ 2018}
            {Member of the foo research team}
            {Foo society}
            {Working on a new foo}

        \entryitem
            {2014}
            {Graduation to master of bar}
            {Bar school}
            {The juxtaposition of foo and bar}
            & \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
\rlap{\parbox[t]{\zzz}{\lipsum[2]}}}\\
    \end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but it's not what I intended to do. First, it seems to be impossible to make a command out of this and call it the `\AtBeginDocument{}` command. Furthermore it only works if you add the `multicolumn` to the `entryitem` as you did. The way my code was intended to work is to replace `\multicolumn{2}{p{6cm}}{\itshape #4}` by your `\multicolumn{2}{l}{%
\rlap{\parbox[t]{\zzz}{\itshape #4}}}`. This does not produce any errors, but it also does not span the `parbox` to the full width.

Comment: In the mean time I tried to get this to work the way you intended it to but unfortunately I was unsuccessfull. Maybe @DavidCarlisle or seomeone else has a better idea.